# Which Chrome's handle should I get to get a specific image within the Internet?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, winapi, handle

I want to make test program that search Google logo image in Google main web page and show coordinate of Google logo in Google web page.

So i tried to get Handle of Chrome but i couldn't get Handle of that.
I used Findwindow() and EnumWindows() to get handle of chrome. This functions are good at bringing handle values from other applications except chrome. But I don't think it cannot get the handle only when the target is chrome.

And i also tried to use Spy++ to get handle. ClassName is 'Intermediate D3D Window' and I tired it, but i failed to operate it;

how to get a handle on chrome??

Comment: Which handle. Window or process. And which window or which process. There are always many of each.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Handle of Chrome window. for example i want to detect Google logo image in Google main page and if image is detected, i want to get coordinate of 
 image

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The function for searching image has already been created, but in order to work, I need to know the handle of the window i want to search. but Chrome's handle are not obtained using FindWindow or EnumWindows.

Comment: That doesn't sound very plausible, that chrome windows aren't unumerable

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So, I want to know how to get handle of Chrome's handle

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yeah, I just confirmed that. I didn't know that. Do you know which window I have to get to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can view `class` and `caption` with WinExplorer(This is a third-party tool, I don't guarantee its security).

[image: 1]

Then use 
`HWND handle = FindWindow("Chrome_WidgetWin_1", "Google - Google Chrome");`return  window handle.

You can also use `HWND handle = FindWindowEx(NULL, NULL, "Chrome_WidgetWin_1", NULL);` return chrome handle.